# If $X$ has a log-normal distribution, what is the distribution of $Y=\exp X$?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution

I'm just looking for the name of this distribution, assuming it has a name. I call it the log-log normal distribution, for lack of a better term. It's support domain is $[1, \infty]$.

Comment: Curious why you are interested.  Given how any process evolve geometrically or exponentially (in the limit as one moves to continuous time), I am stunned how much science is done assuming normal (or t-state) distributions when the lognormal itself is  the clearer and better choice.  Is there a specific reason you are interested in the exponentiation of a lognormal itself?

Comment: @eSurfsnake: yes, it is a very good approximation to the distribution of $\sqrt{X_1 + \sqrt{X_2 + \sqrt{X_3 + \cdots}}}$ when the $X_k$'s are i.i.d log-normal: see section 3.1. in this article:  https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables

Comment: Why is that distribution interesting, aside from how it looks on the page?

Comment: @eSurfsnake: It's one of the most obvious choices for these nested radicals. My interest is mostly experimental math / probabilistic number theory, and this leads sometimes to new distributions being found, quite frequently with applications in Fintech or cryptography. Also, I would love to find a real attractor for this system (just like Gaussian is by far the main attractor in the CLT framework), and log-log-normal is close to being one here for nested radicals.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea, but I don't think I have any insight to bring.  Good luck! I'll keep looking because it is an interesting question.

Comment: I don't find it to be a good approximation at all: I have (numerically) calculated the distribution of that iterated root, as well as simulating it as a check, and even for small geometric SDs the exponentiated iterated root has noticeable skewness.

Comment: @Whuber: Between the 3-th and 97-th percentile the approximation is pretty good, (see my spreadsheet at http://www.datashaping.com/NSR-Whuber.xlsx, compare columns I and K), but beyond those limits, it is not as good, maybe due to not many sampled values falling in the extreme percentiles. In any case, the two distributions are definitely not identical. Most importantly, if you have a better approximation, please let me know.

Comment: I don't have an approximation for this case.  I am relying on an exact calculation.  ("Exact" in the same sense as a numerical quadrature, for instance: that is, it's numerical, it's subject to floating point and discretization error, but in principle can be carried out to within any desired (but nonzero) error tolerance.)  I also have a method to bound the distribution within a potentially narrow "p-box" when the distribution of $X_1$ is discrete with finite support.

Comment: @Whuber: I suppose we are talking about approximating $F_Z$, the distribution, not the density $f_Z$. When $X_1$ is discrete and takes only on a finite number of values, the distribution $F_Z$ seems nowhere differentiable, but excellent approximations are available, see the first picture in my article on the subject, at https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables. Anyway, what I've accomplished so far is a rough understanding and approximations, sounds like an exciting topic where many things have yet to be discovered.

Comment: That's correct: it's important to work with $F_Z$ for the reasons you give.  But of course when $F_Z$ is differentiable, one can differentiate it numerically to compute $f_Z$ (which I have also done in order to provide a visual assessment of the distributional shape).

Comment: @Whuber: would love to see it! (you can email me at vincentg@datasciencecentral.com, not sure if we are allowed on CV to reveal your email address, if not please delete this comment.)

Comment: The method to communicate contact info is through [your profile.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/241137/vincent-granville?tab=profile)  I'm currently too busy to describe my approach in any detail, but I hope to at least sketch it in a reply to one of your questions sometime. For now let it suffice that $F_Z$ is the fixed point of a transformation defined on the set of distribution functions of nonnegative support; this fixed point exists provided $F_X$ doesn't have an (incredibly) heavy right tail; and iterating the transformation starting with *any* distribution rapidly converges.